# PNG only scales from large to normal size instead of normal to small with IMG-Responsive

Tags: image, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, png, image-scaling

I'm having a problem scaling a png image with a transparent background with a width of 279 pixels and height of 432 pixels with class img-responsive on bootstrap3.

**The Problem:**

> Whenever, I upload the png image inside the img tag with the class=
>   "img-fluid" it remains the same size as I scale. Other images seems to
>   work fine, but if I try to upload a bigger image it will become
>   responsive but only scale from very large to normal size, not from
>   normal to small.

My question is

**What is the best way to optimize a PNG image for Bootstrap-3 with the class img-responsive?**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="poster">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">

            <div class="intro-heading">Welcome <img href="../html/indexfinal.html" class="bigv" src="../images/logos/bigvlogo.png" alt=""/> <img href="../html/indexfinal.html" class="midv" src="../images/logos/midvlogo.png" alt=""/> </div>
            <div class="intro-lead-in">Hi yall'</div>       

            <div class="container-fluid">

            <img class="mascot" src="../images/mascot/wave.png">

            </div>
             <a style="float:left" id="guestsignup"></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you used relative path in the fiddle....that's why images are not there...add absolute/full path

Comment: I think your original problem is just that you misspelled "img-responsive".  I just added that to your image in the fiddle and it re-sized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It will work.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4017/4717107886_dcc1270a65_b.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Resize the screen to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `img-responsive` class to existing code:

```
<img class="mascot img-responsive" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4017/4717107886_dcc1270a65_b.jpg">
```

Hope that is what you are looking for.